# Which recruitable characters lock out other recruitment choices?

Tags: chrono-cross

I have started a new game of ''Chrono Cross'' after completing it a long, long while ago. I don't remember any details about the companions.

I did some FAQ checking and it turns out some characters being recruited locks out others.

I'd just like to know, in a minimal spoiler fashion, which ones I should be on the lookout for.

For example, in my newly started game, I started going for Pierre because I didn't remember recruiting him in my first playthrough… but the FAQ I've checked reveals getting him is permanently locking out Nikki and Guile, which I'm sure I would prefer. I did save beforehand so I'll revert this and go for Nikki probably.

So, similarly, I'd like to be warned in advance of such "risky" lock-outs so I can make a decision and get the right characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those groups are:

Korcha, Razzly, and Mel - To get this group you must choose to (SPOILER)

> Save Kid

or

Macha, Glenn, and Doc - To get this group you must choose to (SPOILER)

> Not Save Kid, don't worry, she'll be okay

Edit: Your first trip to the manor you will pick between Guile, Nikki and Pierre

Comment: I think it might be worth linking each "initial" character pick to the others it exclusively unlocks in your answer. This makes it possible to see which to pick to ensure you get a given companion.

Comment: @leokhorn I edited my answer with what decision you'll have to choose to get them.

Comment: Also probably worth noting that you can get all the characters simultaneously if you do New Game +, right?  (Takes three playthroughs though)

Comment: @Shinrai That is correct, you can. Three playthroughs are needed.